# how to copy the column values for the same value in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy column values `author` based on another column `test_method` in the same table.

see table below

```
mysql> select * from testcase;
+------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+
| id   | test_class          | test_method            | author     |
+------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+
| 3062 | IPv4                | InvalidAddress         | N/A        | 
| 3063 | a.b.c.d.AddressIPv4 | InvalidAddress         | larrycai   |
| 3064 | IPv4                | NormalAddress          | N/A        |
| 3065 | a.b.c.d.AddressIPv4 | NormalAddress          | caiyu      |
....
+------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+
202 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The value `N/A` in `author` column needs to be copied from the same value of `test_method` column. (no need to check, just overwrite)

Expected result is

```
mysql> select * from testcase;
+------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+
| id   | test_class          | test_method            | author     |
+------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+
| 3062 | IPv4                | InvalidAddress         | larrycai   | 
| 3063 | a.b.c.d.AddressIPv4 | InvalidAddress         | larrycai   |
| 3064 | IPv4                | NormalAddress          | caiyu      |
| 3065 | a.b.c.d.AddressIPv4 | NormalAddress          | caiyu      |
....
+------+---------------------+------------------------+------------+
202 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I achieve it using SQL command ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.id, t.class, t.test_method,
       (case when t.author = 'N/A'
             then (select t2.author
                   from t t2
                   where t2.test_method = t.test_method and
                         t2.author <> 'N/A'
                   limit 1
                  )
             else t.author
         end) as author
from t;
```

You can also do this with an aggregation and `join`:

```
select t.id, t.class, t.test_method,
       (case when t.author = 'N/A' then tt.author else t.author end) as author
from t left join
     (select test_method, max(author) as author
      from t
      where author <> 'N/A'
      group by test_method
     ) tt
     on t.test_method = tt.test_method;
```

EDIT:

This is easy enough to do as an `update`.  For instance:

```
update t 
    from t left join
         (select test_method, max(author) as author
          from t
          where author <> 'N/A'
          group by test_method
         ) tt
         on t.test_method = tt.test_method;
    set t.author = tt.author
    where t.author = 'N/A';
```

Comment: I need to update the table. the expected table is the one after change.